# RegEx for /*.txt

Tags: regex

I bet this is simple but I just can't find an answer.  I need to write a RegEx for

/*.txt

all being anything... for example, /sdSfssB.txt

Thanks so much!!!

Comment: What regex have you tried?

Comment: `\/.*?\.txt` - a slash followed by anything until you get to .txt

Answer (score 1):

The `.` character will match any characters within a regular expression, so you just need to slightly adjust your existing code :

```
/.*\.txt
```

The `.*` will match any number of any characters, so if you wanted to explicitly target file names that contained at least one character, you should consider using `.+` instead :

```
/.+\.txt
```

Comment: If the string contains a full path, it'll get everything after the first `/`. Maybe `/[^/]*\.txt` would be a better alternative.

Comment: And if it's JS (language/flavor should **always** be tagged in regex questions), you'll need to escape the `/`.

Comment: Thank you - /.*\.txt worked for me!  Perfect! Thank you!